# NetworkInfo.isConnected() returns true, but not able to retrieve interface IP address

Tags: android, restcomm

I have registered an Android broadcast receiver to check when Wifi becomes available (notice that I have added ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE in the manifest):

```
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
  // register for connectivity related events
  androidContext.registerReceiver(this, filter, null, handler);
  ...
```

Then, when I get the broadcast event I check if it is Wifi and if NetworkInfo.isConnected() returns true. If so, I try to retrieve the Wifi interface IP address:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
  ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

  NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (activeNetwork != null) {
     if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        RCLogger.w(TAG, "Connectivity event: WIFI");

        WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) androidContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
        int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
        stringAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);
     }
```

At that point I would expect that stringAddress is the valid IP address of the Wifi interface, but instead it is 0.0.0.0.

It seems like a timing issue, because if I sleep for 5 seconds before I try to retrieve the IP address after I get the event, it works fine and the used Wifi IP address is used

Thanks, 
Antonis